# Garbage value being displayed while freeing a pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am not sure why a garbage value is being thrown in the if loop when i try to free dataToWrite. It works fine in else loop.
Can anyone help me with this?

```
FILE *readFilePointer = NULL;
Message_buf outputMsgBuffer;
char fileData[PIPE_BUF];
char *dataToWrite=NULL;

readFilePointer = fopen(fileToReadFrom, "r");

if (readFilePointer == NULL)
{
    outputMsgBuffer.messageType=1;
    dataToWrite=(char *)malloc(strlen(strcat(fileToReadFrom," does not exists!!"))+1);
    memset(dataToWrite,0,strlen(dataToWrite));
    dataToWrite=strcat(fileToReadFrom," does not exists!!");
    strcat(outputMsgBuffer.messageText,dataToWrite);
    memset(dataToWrite,0,strlen(dataToWrite)+1);
    free(dataToWrite);
}
else
{   
    //outputMsgBuffer.messageText[0] = '\0';
    while (fgets(fileData, sizeof(fileData), readFilePointer) != NULL)
    {
        dataToWrite=(char *)malloc(sizeof(fileData));
        memset(dataToWrite,0,strlen(dataToWrite));
        strcpy(dataToWrite,fileData);
        strcat(outputMsgBuffer.messageText,dataToWrite);    
        free(dataToWrite);
    }

    fclose(readFilePointer);
}
outputMsgBuffer.messageType=1;
outputMsgBuffer.messageLength=strlen(outputMsgBuffer.messageText);
mesg_send(fd,&outputMsgBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Comment: what symbol is garbage.  How is it "thrown"?  What is the "if loop"?

Comment: I agree completely with Oli, however, I happened to notice that you're misusing strcat.

Comment: strlen on dataToWrite() is bad - you don't know what it's contents are - could lead to a UMR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataToWrite=(char *)malloc(strlen(strcat(fileToReadFrom," does not exists!!"))+1);
memset(dataToWrite,0,strlen(dataToWrite));
```

You are not initialising the allocated memory, so calling `strlen` on `dataToWrite` invokes undefined behaviour.

Also, you seem to not be aware of the fact that `strcat` modifies the memory pointed to by its first argument, and returns a pointer to it,

```
dataToWrite=strcat(fileToReadFrom," does not exists!!");
```

throws away the just-allocated memory.

Comment: +1 I didn't even see the `strcat` call, stopped reading at the bad `strlen` in the call to `memset`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this jumps out at me:

```
dataToWrite=(char *)malloc(sizeof(fileData));
memset(dataToWrite,0,strlen(dataToWrite));
```

You're calling `strlen` on a `char*` that points to memory you just allocated with `malloc`.  You have no idea what is going to be in that chunk of memory, yet you call `strlen` which looks for a null character before returning.  Your `memset` is wrong and could be writing anywhere, leading to corrupt memory.

On a side note, don't cast the return value of malloc in C. It is completely unnecessary and can actually hide the fact (in older versions of the standard) that you forgot to include stdlib.h

Answer (score 0):

```
dataToWrite=(char *)malloc(strlen(strcat(fileToReadFrom," does not exists!!"))+1);
```

You've copied a string into `fileToReadFrom`; are you confident it is large enough to handle the extra string data in addition to the filename that it had? (And *why* does this have to happen here? Don't try to do too much in one line.)

I have a suspicion that you've misunderstood how `strcat(3)` works; take another look at the prototype:

```
   char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

The `dest` *is* the destination:

```
dataToWrite=(char *)malloc(strlen(strcat(fileToReadFrom," does not exists!!"))+1);
memset(dataToWrite,0,strlen(dataToWrite));
dataToWrite=strcat(fileToReadFrom," does not exists!!");
```

Assume `fileToReadFrom` contained `hello`. After this code, `dataToWrite` contains:

```
hello does not exists!! does not exists!!
```

If `fileToReadFrom` was *not* large enough, then you've scribbled over a *lot* of unrelated memory.

I strongly recommend finding *every* use of `strcpy(3)` in your program and audit each one for correctness. You may have exploitable security flaws in the rest of the program.

Answer (score 0):

There are many problems in your code.

```
dataToWrite=(char *)malloc(strlen(strcat(fileToReadFrom," does not exists!!"))+1);
```

are you sure fileToReadFrom has enough space?

```
dataToWrite=strcat(fileToReadFrom," does not exists!!");
```

again, are you sure? ... then you are overwriting your pointer to the new allocated memory

```
free(dataToWrite);
```

dataToWrite does not contain the pointer from malloc anymore.

```
strcat(outputMsgBuffer.messageText,dataToWrite);
```

you are sure outputMsgBuffer.messageText has enough space? if yes, why are you allocating memory for another pointer (in the else too)?

What you probably want is:

```
strcpy(outputMsgBuffer.messageText,fileToReadFrom); 
strcat(outputMsgBuffer.messageText," does not exists!!");
```

and in the else

```
strcpy(outputMsgBuffer.messageText,fileData);
```

and nothing else (if you are sure outputMsgBuffer.messageText is big enough).